# How to exclude relations in a query (graph shown in the browser)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Given: 3 nodes labelled A, B, C

Graph: (A)-[1]-(B), (B)-[2]-(C), (A)-[2]-(C)

Desired: A query that returns nodes where relation name is not "2" starting from (A).

Tried:

`Match (n:A)-[r]-(x) where type(r)<>"2" return n,r,x`

AND

`MATCH p=(n:A)--(y) WHERE ALL(z in relationships(p) WHERE type(z) <> "2" RETURN n,y`

Though I get in the browser a graph that includes all relations from (A) including "2" - in this case (A)-[2]-(C)

Maybe just thinking wrong - how would I exclude a dedicated relation from the graph shown in the neo4j browser?

Comment: Turn off "Auto-Complete" in the bottom-right corner of your visualizer window.

Comment: Embarrasing - that did the trick. Thanks, wasnt aware of thise feature.

Comment: It catches everyone at least once :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what is happening with your data or query, but if I created some test data

```
create (a:A {name: 'A'})-[:`1`]->(b:B {name: 'B'})
create (b)-[:`2`]->(c:C {name: 'C'} )
create (a)-[:`2`]->(c)
return *
```

I have a graph that looks like this...

[image]

Then if i query it with your first query

```
match (n:A)-[r]-(x) 
where type(r)<>"2" 
return n,r,x
```

Then neo4j only returns the **A** and **B** nodes that are joined by the relationship with type **1**.

[image]

Is it possible there is some whitespace in your data somewhere in your query that is causing your query to not return the results you expect?